# Split-Path doesn't like colons in the Leaf

Tags: powershell, cognos, cognos-11

**tl;dr**

Is there a way to use `Split-Path` to get the parent path when the leaf name contains a colon (`:`)?  Or is there a better solution than `Split-Path`?

**Full version:**

Using PowerShell 5.1.19041.2673 on Windows 10.

I'm trying to extract the parent container name from a path string.  But this is NOT a path in a Windows file system.  It's a path stored as a string in an XML document.  Technically, it relates to folders and content in a system (Cognos Analytics).  The data is stored as a text value in an XML file (the report spec).

I have some path values that look like:

```
/content/folder[@name='Reports']/folder[@name='Administrative']/folder[@name='Audit']/package[@name='Merchant Code']/model[@name='2015-10-22T22:25:20.362Z']
```

Rather than creating my own function to handle this, I thought I could use `Split-Path`.

```
Split-Path (Split-Path $b) -Leaf
```

But if the leaf value contains a colon (like my example):

```
Split-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string.
At line:5 char:28
+ "parent name  $(Split-Path (Split-Path $a) -Leaf)"
+                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Split-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SplitPath
```

This works:

```
$a = "/a/b/c/model"
"parent path  $(Split-Path $a)"
"parent path  $(Split-Path $a -Parent)"
"leaf         $(Split-Path $a -Leaf)"
"parent name  $(Split-Path (Split-Path $a) -Leaf)"
```

Output:

```
parent path  \a\b\c
parent path  \a\b\c
leaf         model
parent name  c
```

But if I add a colon into the leaf:

```
$a = "/a/b/c/mod:el"
Split-Path $a
Split-Path $a -Leaf
```

Output:

```
Split-Path $a
Split-Path $a -Leaf

mod:el
```

As you can see, there is no problem returning the leaf value, but the parent path is an empty string (line 3).

I even tried to escape the colon:

```
$a = "/a/b/c/mod`:el"
Split-Path $a
Split-Path $a -Leaf
```

Same results.  And if the parent path (result of `Split-Path`) is blank, that causes the error.

Comment: I'm not sure if tagging this with the the Cognos tags is appropriate here.  I'm trying to use data from a Cognos report spec, but the question is really about processing text in PowerShell.  Feel free to edit the tags if you have more expertise managing posts on SO than I do.

Comment: I think you could use the api here instead of the cmdlet: `[System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($a)` outputs `\a\b\c` for me

Comment: It works, but will it always work?  Does this require any libraries, etc. other than what comes with PowerShell that I may have unwittingly installed?

Comment: this is .net and powershell has full access to .net, there is no need to install anything.

Comment: A simple workaround: `($a -split '[/\\]')[-1]`

Answer (score 1):

What operating system are you running the command on?  If you are running this command on windows, then the reason that the command is failing is because the colon character is an invalid character and cannot be a part of the path.  If you are running it on any other operating system, what happens if you try escaping the colon like so:

```
$a = "/a/b/c/mod`:el"
```

Comment: I tried that already and forgot to mention it.  I have updated the question

Comment: Yep, `Split-Path` works specifically with folder/registry paths, neither of which can have a `:` in the middle of them. You could use `-qualifier` or `-noqualifier` to get everything before or everything after the `:` but that's all.